# Depth sensor double vision

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm getting a double image from the depth sensor, both in the Explorer and via Unity SDK. The object (in this instance my hand) is about 40-100cm away which should be within the specs. Does anybody know if this is a "normal" behavior? [See the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxUJO.png) (build KOT49H.160920 and yes, the cameras are clean :)

Answer (score 0):

The point cloud data callback provides a shared buffer.
You have to copy this buffer before processing it. Because, the buffer will be overwritten with new depth data and than will again invoke the callback.
It seems to me that your are processing the buffer directly. This will lead to corrupt data and you are rendering mixed new and old data!